# Pagination in C++ (console)

Tags: c++, pagination

I have 100 student records and I want to show the number of records which is entered from the keyboard per page. Users press the arrow button and they can see the next list. How do I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Unfortunately your question is too vague - can you provide more detail - what have you tried so far ?

Comment: You could simply achieve this effect with piping the output into `less` (assuming you're on a platform where `less` is available). Though, this probably won't work if your program expects user input from console as well. So, [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) could be your 2nd chance.